# Angular: use "Component" as type in an interface

Tags: angular, interface, components

How can I define that property inside an interface has to be a class having the `Component` decorator?

To add some more info, I am trying to create this interface:

```
interface WidgetConfig {
      ...
      component: any;
      ...
    }
```

Where `component` property should be an Angular component class instead of `any`.

Is it possible with Angular Ivy?

Comment: It depends.. what does component represent? A reference or an actual instance of a component?

Comment: @MikeOne it represents the class, not the instance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Typescript does have Generic constraints, but the constraint is on the actual type. The only way you could do this would be to create your own interface. As an example :

Create an interface (Can be empty or can have common methods).

```
export interface IComponent {
}
```

Add it to all of your components :

```
export class AppComponent implements IComponent {
}
```

Then modify your WidgetConfig interface like so :

```
interface WidgetConfig<T extends IComponent> {
    component: T;
}
```

Then the only instances of WidgetConfig that can be created must be given a type that inherits from IComponent. It's an additional step, but actually one that you may want to do anyway (For example, Not all components may be valid for WidgetConfig etc).

Comment: Unfortunately, in my situation, I want components to be unaware of the fact they will be used inside WidgetConfig, so this suggestion doesn't fit my needs. It looks good anyway for similar cases :)